# Is there a way to read the details/metadata on a file in Open File Dialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Like the title says, I'm opening a file using

```
QFiledialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "C:/", "PDF (*.pdf)")
```

Is there anyway to get the details/metadata like the date, owner, etc. of said file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Qt library.

If I'm not mistaken, you have a FileDialog object. This object has a function, named .open(), which requires a QFile object in the parameters. With this qfile object, you can construct a QFileInfo object, which has several functions for getting metadata.

You can read more here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html